# PCAとt-SNEを使って目的の結果になるようにしたいです！

Tags: python, python3

現在の状況：PCAのスクリプトをpaiza(beta)に打ち込んだが以下のようなエラーが出て実行が出来ない。

File "Main.py", line 6
d_pca <- prcomp(coil20[,-ncol(coil20)], scale=TRUE)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

最終目的：以下のリンクにあるような実行結果を得たい。　※この質問内にも目的の画像は載せています
https://blog.albert2005.co.jp/2015/12/02/tsne/

現在の状態を分かりやすいように画像で記しておきます
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

最終目的の画像は以下の画像になります
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

環境：OS windows10
　　　python3.8

Comment: そもそも参考にしているサイトはR言語ではないですか？

Comment: R言語みたいです！
言語変えたら良さそうですが、また違うエラーが出てきました。。違う方でまた質問させてもらいたいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

言語設定を変更したら実行できました。pythonのコードをR言語の基盤で書いてしまったことが問題だったみたいです